# Tabs on the front page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, user-interface

It seems someone’s just broke teh CSS ...
[image]

Comment: Also on meta...

Comment: @Asaf: Right, that was a bad choice of a word. I meant the default page with the list of questions, as opposed to e.g. http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/bug , where the tabs display OK. Also, I should note that the bug is MO-specific, it doesn’t affect other SE sites.

Comment: The problem seems gone. (I had it, and now it is fine again.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry about that. We accidentally pushed a set of changes earlier that wasn't meant to go public just yet. The change has been reverted, and things should be back to normal.

Comment: It's happening again! D:

Comment: @AsafKaragila A fix is rolling out now. Sorry 'bout that.

Comment: Thanks. It's better again. I suddenly thought that you guys switched to the new and improved Hitchhiker's Guide. Because it seemed that the tabs on the front page just read "**P A N I C**" :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Do you know where your towel is?

Comment: Of course. In my backpack I always carry a small towel, just in case.